# How to erase the drawing using button click?

Tags: ios

I have some troubles with drawing app in IOS. I have created the free hand drawing with the help of some tutorials. But I found some difficulties in erasing the drawing. In my app, I have button with eraser as background image. After I clicked the eraser button, when I swipes over the drawing, it will erase the drawing wherever I swipes. Can anyone help me to do this. 
Thanks in advance.

Given below is my code:

```
@implementation LinearInterpView
{
    UIBezierPath *path;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {

    if(self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        path=[UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path setLineWidth:2.0];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{
    [[UIColor blackColor] setStroke];
    [path stroke];
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p=[touch locationInView:self];
    [path moveToPoint:p];
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch=[touches anyObject];
    CGPoint p=[touch locationInView:self];
    [path addLineToPoint:p];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [self touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

-(void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    [self touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

// This is the button action to erase the drawing.
- (IBAction)erase:(id)sender {
    CGContextRef cgref=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetBlendMode(cgref, kCGBlendModeClear);
}
```

Kindly clear me, what mistake I did.

Comment: drawRect gets called everytime when you are making a stroke, so in your drawRect you are setting stroke color as black everytime it is being called, therefore I want to ask you that when you press the erase button and try erasing, do you get a black stroke or not?

Comment: yes, absolutely the strokes are black in color.I have a doubt too,If I want to erase means I need to call drawRect Method. Is it so, what are the changes to be made in the code, without affecting the drawings in black color and also it will erase the lines.

Comment: well, the easy way is to use a bool value and in the erase button action, set the bool and in draw rect method set the color of your stroke to either black or white depending upon the bool value.

Comment: Thank you sir. I have tried this idea. But there is also an issue, if i trying to erase the black line drawing, the black lines turned into fade colour lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not you implement the same logic in the erasor button as you did in the draw button. just make the default color of the stroke in the eraser as white color or what ever color your background is.

Comment: You can may be post code snippet and I can check it out for you?

Answer (score 1):

So by drawing you mean you have drew lines on the screen say with some color you can do the same by setting white color and alpha 1 so that white lines replace the existing colored lines. A better  [tutorial here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/18840/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-app-with-uikit) . [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4121184/ios-open-source-drawing-application-source-code) also seemed important.

Comment: Yes, Two days before I had just crossed that tutorial. but I didnt try. It has so many functionalities. Confusing little bit.

Comment: can you show us what you tried thus far, we will be in a better position to help you.

Comment: Sir, I have edited my question with my code. Please clear my mistake. what if i suppose to do to erase my drawing.

Comment: Ok lets try one small fix here, have a bool for eraser and set it up to NO by default then when eraser is clicked set it to YES. Use this bool in drawRect if it is yes then color should be whiteColor not black else it can be any other color you want.

Comment: Sir I tried your above mentioned idea. If click the button and drag the mouse over the drawing, the black lines also changed into white color lines.

Comment: so they did those white lines cover the black lines?? I mean erase them?

Comment: If I erase means the spaces will be in white. But If I drag the mouse over the black lines i.e on drawing,the drawing in black color changed into white color lines that means black lines turned into faded light color lines.

Answer (score 1):

First of all your logic should be make a layer on ImageView.

then you can draw on that layer then pass white color to erase.

It'll look like erase and your view will look like according to requirement.

That will surly work.

Comment: Yes, It will be.Further process is to save this as text and have to display as a data on the tableview.

Comment: @Vidhya i also stuck here, if you done it please help

Answer (score 1):

Try this to erase drawing in iOS:

```
- (IBAction)eraserPressed:(id)sender { 
    red = 255.0/255.0;
    green = 255.0/255.0;
    blue = 255.0/255.0;
    opacity = 1.0;
}
```